# Ssh connection with raspberry pi 3

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, raspberry-pi3

I'm really new to linux and its my first raspberry pi. I want to connect my laptop(which has ubuntu as OS) and my raspberry(with ubuntu server) via ssh and I followed the steps by confuguring the ssh_config and sshd_config files, authorized keys with permissions, I set Password_Authentication to yes, created Allow_Users and added my username etc. But every time i want to connect with ssh username@host it says permission denied. I also dont know, which of the config files I have to edit. As I know, the ssh_config is for the client and sshd_config for the server, so do I have to edit both files on both systems or what exactly could be the error? As now, I edited the ssh_config on my laptop and the sshd_config on the raspberry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe check out your log files to debug the errors. Check out this command below:
sudo grep sshd /var/log/auth.log

the sudo command stands for superuser do it is an administrator keyword

grep: allows you to search through text

sshd: you know what that is

then the path to where we are searching for is the logfiles for authentication

Check out the links below also:
https://www.ssh.com/ssh/config/
https://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/

*Also, make sure you have SSH enabled on the raspberry pi

Sorry I'm not more help I haven't done this on a pi yet.

Comment: i have installed the package krfb and tried it again and it connected finally! But to be honest, I have no clue, what happened.